# Codeigniter Lightbox does not show contact page

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I am using lightbox script in my codeigniter project. The following code i put in my register page.

```
_BASE_URL="<?php echo base_url();?>";

jQuery(function ($) {

    var contact = {
        message: null,
        init: function () {

            $('#contact-form input.contact, #contact-form a.contact').click(function (e) {

                e.preventDefault();

                // load the contact form using ajax
                $.get(_BASE_URL+"index.php/register/lightcontact", function(data){
                    // create a modal dialog with the data
                    $(data).modal({
                        closeHTML: "<a href='#' title='Close' class='modal-close'>x</a>",
                        position: ["10px", null],
                        overlayId: 'contact-overlay',
                        containerId: 'contact-container',
                        onOpen: contact.open,
                        onShow: contact.show,
                        onClose: contact.close

                    });
                });
            });
        },
```

When click on a link 'Contact', it should show the pop up lightbox. But It does not show. While seeing the page source, the include files are correctly include. Could anybody help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Yes. i have got like this : http://localhost/ci_sam/index.php/register/lightcontact

Comment: Also Firebug does not show any error while clicking the contact link. But popup window does not open. Please help me.

Comment: public function lightcontact()
{ $this->load->view('contact');
}

Comment: Are you calling `contact.init()`?

Comment: Yes. I have called contact.init() at last.

Comment: Where i have to put <?php include("lightcontact.php"); ?> ? By using this, May i get contact page as lightbox popup window from register page?

Comment: I am using Simplemodal light box script. Just i have changed the URL as shown in my Question. Could you please tell me the jquery changes? In normal PHP page, it does work fine. But in Codeigniter, it does not work.

Comment: Yes, you just need to put <?php include... in your register page. You'll have to address the html of your view directly in JQuery though, instead of $(data).modal

Comment: can you post the lightcontact.php code? If you do that I can give you the exact code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the top of your register page, include your contact view like this:

```
<?php include("lightcontact.php"); ?>
```

In lightcontact.php, your div should look a little like this:

```
<div id="contactmodal">
...
</div>
```

Now change your JQuery to this:

```
$("#contactmodal").modal({
                    closeHTML: "<a href='#' title='Close' class='modal-close'>x</a>",
                    position: ["10px", null],
                    overlayId: 'contact-overlay',
                    containerId: 'contact-container',
                    onOpen: contact.open,
                    onShow: contact.show,
                    onClose: contact.close

                });
```

Hopes this helps, don't hesitate to ask further questions